# Разница между override и virtual

Tags: c++, ооп

Многие примеры на сайтах показывают использование `virtual` в объявлении класса, но в дочерних нет никакого `override`. На msdn.microsoft.com же наоборот пихают `virtual` также и дочернему классу, + `override`.

Хотелось бы узнать, вот если я вызываю из базового класса метод

```
void Base::Method() {

},
```

Который не переопределяется, а в этом методе используются методы, которые переопределены в дочерних классах - они будут переопределены автоматически или только в случае `(Son *) (ptr)->Method2()`? И как будет выглядеть ситуация в обоих случаях если `virtual void Base::Method2() = 0;`?

---

Вопрос из [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/490122/6) участника [@ Artem](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/201200/artem).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`virtual` указывает, что дочерний класс может переопределить метод. Это совсем не означает, что в дочернем классе будет `override`. Он **может** быть.

> На msdn.microsoft.com же наоборот пихают `virtual` также и дочернему
>   классу, + `override`.

К дочернем классам добавляют `virtual` к методу, чтобы указать, что его потомки так же могут переопределить метод.

Про вторую часть вопроса:

```
class Base{

    void Method() { bar(); }
    virtual void bar(); { }

};

class A : public Base {

    virtual void bar() { }

};

class B : public A {

    virtual void bar() { // do something 
    }

};
```

Сделав так:

```
A* myObject = new B();
myObject->Method();
```

Вызовется метод из класса `B`.

Собственно, возвращаясь к `virtual`. Я мог в классах `A` и `B` не объявлять методы как `virtual`, всё равно сработает метод из `B`.

Точно так же, независимо от того, напишу я так  `virtual void bar()` в `B` классе или так `virtual void bar() override`, тоже ничего не изменится. Что с `override`, что без него метод дочернего класса перекроет метод базового. Просто написав `override` мы явно это указываем. Очень полезно, если вы с кодом работаете не один.

Comment: @Abyx а я и не говорил, что обязательна.

Answer (score 0):

Когда мы объявляем функцию виртуальной, используя `virtual`, то это равносильно тому, как если бы мы обращались к ней не напрямую, а через указатель.

```
typedef void (*functionPointer)(ClassA*);

struct ClassA {
   functionPointer func1;
   bool called;
};

void callMe(ClassA* thisA) { thisA->called = true; }

ClassA ca;
ca.called = false;
ca.func1 = callMe;
ca.func1(&ca); // Будет вызвана функция callMe().
```

Поэтому при обращении к перекрытому методу всегда будет вызвана именно "последняя" версия функции. Даже если обращаться к ней, указывая класс-предок.

C помощью *override* можно избежать случайного поведения наследования в коде.В следующем примере показано, в какой ситуации без использования *override* поведение функции-члена производного класса может быть случайным.

Компилятор не выдает ошибки при использовании этого кода.

```
class BaseClass
{
    virtual void funcA();
    virtual void funcB() const;
    virtual void funcC(int = 0);
    void funcD();
};

class DerivedClass: public BaseClass
{
    virtual void funcA(); // ok, работает как подразумевается

    virtual void funcB(); // DerivedClass::funcB() не const, так что он не перекрывает
                          // BaseClass::funcB() const и является новым методом

    virtual void funcC(double = 0.0); // DerivedClass::funcC(double) имеет другой
                                      // тип параметра, чем BaseClass::funcC(int), так что
                                      // DerivedClass::funcC(double) тоже новый метод

};
```

Подробнее можно прочитать [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/jj678987.aspx).